# HTML change site using select tag and php

Tags: php, html, css, html-select

I try to make a website and I'd like to make a select tag where you can change your language. I mean there will be some options which you can change. For example the default site language is English but you're want to change it to German, you can just select the german from the list. After that you click the SAVE button and the page will redirect you to indexgermany.html
I tried to make a code but I am new in php so I don't know how to do this. By the way here is my code:

```js
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($_POST['option']))
{
    if($_POST['option'] == Deutsch - DE) {
    header('Location: indexgerman.php');
    }
}
}

?>
```

```html
<form  method="POST" action="changelang.php">
<select select name="languages" id="langs">
<option for="english" name="english">English - EN</option>
<option for="germany" name="germany">Deutsch - DE</option>
</select><br>
 <input type="submit" class="langsave" name="submit" value="SAVE">
</form>
```

Comment: It appears that you are new to html as well.  The key names for the $_POST variable come from the name of the select box and you need a value attribute on the options for the value of the $_POST variable at that key name.

Comment: Your options should have value attributes

Comment: What's wrong with the given code? Anything not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $selected_lang = $_POST['languages'];
    if($selected_lang == "Deutsch - DE") {
        header('Location: indexgerman.php');
    }else{
        header('Location: indexenglish.php');
    }
}    
?>
```

First thing is when u get the options from `Select` tag, U put name associated with `select` tag not with `option` tag And U missed `""` while comparing to string Values(Deutsch - DE).

Answer (score 0):

I`ll guess your scrict does not redirect you, if you changed the "lang".

If you use the following code it should work:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['option']))
        {
            if($_POST['option'] == 'Deutsch - DE') {
            header('Location: indexgerman.php');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

You forgot to wrap the name of your option in quotes.
This is required because you want to compare 2 strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing value in HTML and $_POST needs to be equal to string, otherwise it just undefined value.

EDIT:

Also $_POST['option'] does not exist, I renamed `select` tag name to options.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if(isset($_POST['option'])){
    if($_POST['option'] == "DE") {
       header('Location: indexgerman.php');
    }
  }
}
?>

<form  method="POST" action="changelang.php">
  <select select name="options" id="langs">
    <option for="english" name="english" value="EN">English - EN</option>
    <option for="germany" name="germany" value="DE">Deutsch - DE</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" class="langsave" name="submit" value="SAVE">
</form>
```